# how to make the css code to be applied for a certain div instead of the entire project div's

Tags: html, css

I am working on angularjs and bootstrap application. I am using the below css code to make the background white color, but issue is the css code is effecting to the entire project. I want to modify the below css code such that it only effects my div.

css code:

```
<style>
svg g:first-of-type rect{
   fill-opacity: 0;
 }
svg g: first-of-type path{
   stroke: #e6e6e6;
}
..
```

html code:

```
<div id="div12ID">

<div class="row">
 ..
</div>
</div>
```

I have many divs in my application and i want the css code shown above to be effected only for the above shown html code.
I tried adding the ID in front of the css code `(#div12ID  svg g:first-of-type rect{ .. } )` but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Your CSS and HTML have no apparent relation to each other. Please include a MCVE. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your style in your css as ".row" and then add class as row in your div tag where you want to use it.
Else you can also do inline styling to your specific div.
Ex:-

```
<div style="width:200px;background:#F9EECF;border:1px dotted black;text-align:center">
```

Generic content...

Comment: I have used <div class="row"> in many places in my project. So I tried using my ID name in front of css code #div12ID  svg g:first-of-type rect{ .. } but it is not effecting. I cannot use inline style as I have many things to be applied so best way would be using the ID# in front of the css code which is not working for me. Any inputs?